# Can I set-up a shared network during install?

Tags: server, networking

I'm in the process of installing Ubuntu Server, though the computer has no wifi-card. Our router is in a different room, and I don't have money for a wifi-card right now. So, until I get a card, I was hoping to use a shared connection from my laptop.

I've figured out how to share the connection from my laptop. Though the installer tries to set up the network, and it fails, even though it's connected via Ethernet to my laptop.

Can anyone offer some guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

James, usually the shared network trick works flawlessly, so that might be a bug in the way it works. It usually sets up a special program called 'dnsmasq' on the shared ethernet device which should give your server a dynamic IP during the installation.

You may be able to work around this problem by simply giving your server a static IP address on the shared network. Open a terminal on the laptop and run

```
ip addr show
```

You should get a list with entries like this:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:6c:87:2c:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.105/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::223:6cff:fe87:2c2d/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Find the interface that is your shared ethernet connection, and note the network, so in my case above:

```
192.168.1.105/24
```

My network is 192.168.1.0/24 and my address is 192.168.1.105

Pick an address (how about 192.168.1.2 in this case) in the same network, and assign it to your server. Give it your machine's address as the gateway and DNS server.

That should work to at least get the server able to transfer files from the internet. However, you still won't be able to use the server from any of your other computers because it will basically be firewalled behind your laptop. You can use "DNAT" rules to enable that, but that sounds a lot more complicated than just saving up for a wifi card. :)